# External jars not loading in built project. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

So, I have exported my project in both Netbeans and Eclipse and when I try to

`java -jar myproject.jar`

I get this prompt

[image: console prompt]

In my project I have some libraries which are located inside of src in Netbeans and out of src in Eclipse as it should (please correct me if I'm wrong) The libraries are included via:

Java Build Path > Add JARs...

I've done some research and it seems that I have to change my JAVA CLASSPATH or somethng like that but I don't know exactly how to do it.

The project works perfectly when I compile it and run it, but it crashes after I build it into a Jar file.

By the way, if it isn't clear enough I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Build path is not the same as runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the path for the jar files and pass it on the command line.

Something like this:

```
ftp_jar=${Utils_home}/bin/ftpClientUtil.jar
net_jar=${Utils_home}/bin/commons-net-3.3.jar
jsch_jar=${Utils_home}/bin/jsch-0.1.51.jar

java -cp .:$jsch_jar:$net_jar:$ftp_jar com.myplace.ftputils.SFTPClientUtil $*
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your program as:

```
java -cp .:[path-of-lib1.jar]:[path-of-lib2.jar] -jar myproject.jar
```

replace [path-of-libX.jar] with actual path of your libraries.